# Looking for a kosher hot plate for Shabbos and Yom Tov

Tags: shabbat, product-recommendation, yom-tov, cooking-bishul, health-safety-shmira

Does anyone know of a kosher hot plate that can be safely left on for the duration of Shabbos, Yom Tov, or a 3 day Shabbos and Yom Tov and will not become a fire hazard?

Every product should be and can be a kosher product.

Bringing any product to market requires competent halachic supervision:

http://www.kosherimage.com/approval.html

Gaining rabbinic approval for a product is critical:

http://www.aish.com/sh/l/48970106.html

There is a huge difference between a product that is manufactured without halachic supervision and a product that is manufactured with proper, competent, orthodox halachic supervision.

Comment: What could make a hot plate not kosher?  If you know of particular properties it must (or mustn't) have, please [edit] that in.  Thanks.

Comment: Seemingly any of these will be a fire hazard if you aren't careful

Comment: Thanks for editing, but I guess I wasn't clear enough (sorry).  I wasn't asking about the importance of kashrut in general, but about the specific case. Lots of things in your kitchen aren't under supervision; they're kosher by default, unless you do something wrong (e.g. can openers, mixing bowls, microwave ovens).  On the other hand, some things require more scrutiny/supervision (e.g. most food, ovens that you want to use on Shabbat (because of lights, temperature change from opening the door...)). It looks like you think hot plates are in the latter category, but why? What issues are there?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://artscroll.com/Books/kplate.html) Shabbos hot plate should do the trick, as the description clearly states:

> The Shabbos Safe Hot Plate was designed by an Electronic Engineering Technician with the first priority being safety. Many observant Jewish families keep their food warm with small appliances that were not originally designed to be safely left on for the duration of Shabbos, Yom Tov or a 3-day Shabbos/Yom Tov. Over a period of time, these devices can fail and become a fire hazard.
>
> The Shabbos Safe Hot Plate was designed from the very start to be left on for extended use, to draw less electricity, to have built-in electrical safe-guards and to be a product that would last for many, many years. It is also built only with parts that are solid and durable. With the Shabbos Safe Hot Plate, you can be confident that you are using a device that will be reliable and safe.
>
> Enjoy hot food on Shabbos and Yom Tov with the Shabbos Safe Hot Plate and without the worry.

Hope this helps.